# How to judge if a URL is already encoded with encodeURI?

Tags: vbscript, javascript, url-encoding

I'm trying to do it in VBScript/JScript, to avoid re-encoding.
Should I judge if there is "%" ? Does "%" have other uses in URL?
Thanks.

**Edit:** Oh, the original encoding function may not be encodeURI.
I'm trying to collect URLs from the browser, and store them after encoding with encodeURI.
But if the URL is already encoded, another encoding will make it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iterate over the chars in the url and test for characters that aren't allowed 
in an url.

if there are any encode it. 
if there aren't any illegal characters, it doesn't matter

Comment: Sounds great. Erm...what characters are illegal then?  
I know even encodeURI and URLencode have different opinions.

Comment: as defined in RFC1738 safe characters are 0-9a-zA-Z and $-_.+!*'(), everything else is unsafe

Comment: The illegal ones are usually: # % & * { } \ : < > ? / +

There are other rules though, such as not having consecutive periods, ending in a period, etc.

Comment: It needs much care, and a new RegExp object. I don't tend to use it. Thank you anwyay.

Comment: you don't need to use regex on this. just make a string containing all the valid chars, iterate over the chars in your url and test if every char in the url is contained in your safe-char-string if you find one that isn't your url needs to be urlencoded

Answer (score 1):

I might try decoding it and comparing the result to the original URL. If it changed or got shorter in length your original URL was probably already encoded.

Comment: Thank you. So a URL which hasn't been encoded can't be decoded. Is this always true?

Comment: I'm not 100% on that -- but it might be an okay starting point. You might run into some funny URLs that won't fit; maybe some that are supposed to have the encoded characters in them.

Comment: OK. This is what I got: decodeURI throws unknown error 800A13A1. Google says it's because the string to be decoded contains illegal characters.